# UNION producing a column of maximum precision of two columns

Tags: sql-server-2005

If you combine columns of different yet convertible data types, the result of the UNION will produce a column data type equal to the maximum precision of the two columns.

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
(
    col1 DECIMAL(5 ,2)
) 
CREATE TABLE tab2
(
    col2 DECIMAL(5 ,2)
)

INSERT INTO tab1
VALUES
  (
    11.5
  ) 
INSERT INTO tab2
VALUES
  (
    11.65
  )

SELECT col1
FROM   tab1 UNION 
SELECT round(col2,0)
FROM   tab2
```

**RESULT:**

> 11.50
>
> 12.00

BUT i should get result as

**RESULT:**

> 11.50
>
> 12

Is there a way to achieve this? col2 values from tab2 should be rounded to integer and should appear as integers in the result.

In reality the queries are not this simple.

*** I have edited my question to suit my actual requirement.***

Comment: Cast to varchar. But that is not good.

Comment: Also, if you want `col1` without decimal point then you should declare it as int like `col2`

Comment: before using union in this way, you should first study the use of [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms180026.aspx) - It has mentioned that `The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
The data types must be compatible.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
SELECT CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(10)) col1
FROM   tab1 UNION 
SELECT CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(10)) col2
FROM   tab2
```

As mentioned in comment by @Giorgi Nakeur not good but can solve issue.

I think you want something like this as per your updated question. See the below.

***Alternate solution,***

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT col1
FROM   tab1 UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND(col2,0) 
FROM   tab2)

SELECT REPLACE(CAST(Col1 AS varchar(10)),'.00','') col1 FROM cte
```

Comment: The solution suggested by @curiousguy doesn't fulfill my edited requirement.

Comment: Just before few minutes back you have changed your question, would be better if you post all your queries in one question. Thanks

Comment: yeah that is correct, but before that I've already answered. your recent edited part `col2 values from tab2 should be rounded to integer and should appear as integers in the result.`